# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string XX while fetching the data from the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, numberformatexception

I am trying to fetch data from the database. and I am getting the following error.

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: An error occurred while converting the nvarchar value to JDBC data type INTEGER.] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "XX"
```

I know it is trying to convert my string into integer. but I dont understand why it is doing that, because my datatype is string only.

My code looks like:

model:

```
package com.a.spring.models;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="CapacityConstraint")
public class CapacityConstraint {


    private int DocEntry;
    private String OpCode;
    private String RsrcCd;
    private String Type;
    private Operation operation;

    @Id
    @Column(name="DocEntry")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getDocEntry() {
        return DocEntry;
    }


    public void setDocEntry(int DocEntry) {
        this.DocEntry = DocEntry;
    }


    @Column(name="OpCode")
    public String getOpCode() {
        return OpCode;
    }


    public void setOpCode(String opCode) {
        OpCode = opCode;
    }


    @Column(name="RsrcCd")
    public String getRsrcCd() {
        return RsrcCd;
    }


    public void setRsrcCd(String rsrcCd) {
        RsrcCd = rsrcCd;
    }


    @Column(name="Type")
    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }


    public void setType(String type) {
        Type = type;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OpCode", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Operation getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }


    public void setOperation(Operation operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }


}
```

Operation model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="[@IS_OPRMASTER]")
public class Operation {
    private int docEntry;
    private String OpCode;
    private String OpName;

    @Id
    @Column(name="DocEntry")

    public int getDocEntry() {
        return docEntry;
    }
    public void setDocEntry(int docEntry) {
        this.docEntry = docEntry;
    }

    @Column(name="U_OpCode")
    public String getOpCode() {
        return OpCode;
    }
    public void setOpCode(String opCode) {
        OpCode = opCode;
    }
    @Column(name="U_OpName")
    public String getOpName() {
        return OpName;
    }
    public void setOpName(String opName) {
        OpName = opName;
    }

}
```

function to fetch data:

```
@Override
    public List<CapacityConstraint> getList() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query= session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CapacityConstraint order by docEntry").addEntity(CapacityConstraint.class);
        List <CapacityConstraint> d=query.list();
        return d;
    }
```

Table capacityconstraint

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CapacityConstraint](
    [DocEntry] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OpCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RsrcCd] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_CapacityConstraint] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocEntry] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

table Operation

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[@IS_OPRMASTER](
    [DocEntry] [int] NOT NULL,
    [U_OpCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [U_OpName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [KIS_OPRMASTER_PR] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocEntry] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Stack trace :

```
Aug 04, 2016 10:52:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [kendo] in context with path [/GanttView] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: An error occurred while converting the nvarchar value to JDBC data type INTEGER.] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "PTHP"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStringToObject(DDC.java:291)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DDC.convertStreamToObject(DDC.java:419)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:2007)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.getValue(dtv.java:175)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Column.getValue(Column.java:113)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:1982)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:1967)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getInt(SQLServerResultSet.java:2219)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getInt(DelegatingResultSet.java:220)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2807)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1477)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:644)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:854)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2382)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2368)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2198)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2193)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1780)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:156)
    at com.kendoui.spring.models.CapacityContraintDaoImpl.getList(CapacityContraintDaoImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getList(Unknown Source)
    at com.kendoui.spring.controllers.CapacityContraintController.read(CapacityContraintController.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It is giving error for the opCode. If I remove the operation model from the capacityConstraint model then it is working fine without giving any error. But if I include it then it is throwing the error. 
So i think the problem is with the @joinColumn statement.

I would really appreciate if someone could solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `XX` is twenty right.

Comment: Maybe `docEntry` is not an int.  Please post your table schema

Comment: Scary wombat : I have added the table schema above. thanks

Comment: Can you post your entire stacktrace?

Comment: Maybe the link between the two tables is DocEntry (why the different type is a mystery however)

Comment: the link between the two tables in opcode actually

Comment: I have added the stack trace above.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are naming 2 column by same name,

> @Column(name="**OpCode**") 
>  public String getOpCode() { 
>  return OpCode; 
>  }

and

> @OneToOne   
>  @JoinColumn(name = "**OpCode**", nullable = false, insertable
>   = false, updatable = false)
>      
>  public Operation getOperation() {
>           return operation;
>       }

One for object reference(foreign key) one for string, so one of them is trying to convert in integer format for foreign key and one in string format.

Comment: Hello Rupesh, I tried changing the column name in the joincolumn statement. but it is giving me The column name U_OpCode is not valid.

Comment: in @JoinColumn(name = "OpCode",  ...) name should be the, name of column having foreign key  to @IS_OPRMASTER, in your table CapacityConstraint, this column is missing.

Comment: Do we have alternative way instead of changing table column?